# How to update npm & NodeJS on Windows without admin rights?

Tags: node.js, npm

I already have npm and NodeJS installed, but both are very outdated and all I want is to update its versions.

I have tried to download the latest NodeJS LTS binary, and then added the path to PATH environment variable. However, running `node -v` or `npm -v` after that gives me the old versions.

Is there any other way to solve this problem?

Uninstalling older NodeJS didn't work without admin right too.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot upgrade nodejs without admin rights. However, you can install separate binaries.

However, if you do have admin rights, run the shell and enter:

```
npm install -g npm-windows-upgrade
npm-windows-upgrade
```

Comment: No, I have no admin rights. I was trying to install the separate binary, but there was no luck. The problem is - NodeJS is already installed in Program Files (probably by administrator) and looks like its path is prioritized. But it is too old, and cannot be updated without admin rights. Is there any chance to solve it by myself without contacting the administrator?